# Real-Time Kafka Data Ingestion into HBase via PySpark - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hbase.client.Put.add([B[B[B)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put;

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, spark-streaming

I try to configure Real-Time Kafka Data Ingestion into HBase via PySpark in accordance to [this tutorial](http://cjcroix.blogspot.com/2015/10/pyspark-hbase-and-spark-streaming-save.html). I have a problem with the code shown below. At the moment I just try to add data to the Hbase table in the simplest possible way like this:

```
def SaveToHBase(rdd):

#     print("=====Pull from Stream=====")

    if not rdd.isEmpty():

        host = 'myhost:2182'
        table = 'logs'  
        keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"  
        valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"  
        conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host,
                "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort": "2182",
            "hbase.mapred.outputtable": table,
            "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",  
            "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",  
            "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}


        rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv)


kds = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topic, k_params, fromOffsets=None)



###################################################################### added
parsed = kds.filter(lambda x: x != None and len(x) > 0 )
parsed = parsed.map(lambda x: x[1])
parsed = parsed.map(lambda x: (str('121323322323'),[str('121323322323'),"log","log",'content']))  

parsed.foreachRDD(SaveToHBase)


############################################################
# Start application
############################################################

runApplication(ssc, config)
```

It seems to me that all jars are compatible with my Hbase 2.0.2. Any ideas why I get error shown below?

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.saveAsHadoopDataset(PythonRDD.scala:583)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 72.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 72.0 (TID 72, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.add([B[B[B)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put;
    at org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter.convert(HBaseConverters.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter.convert(HBaseConverters.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonHadoopUtil$$anonfun$convertRDD$1.apply(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonHadoopUtil$$anonfun$convertRDD$1.apply(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:181)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:139)
    ... 10 more
```

My JARS:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars \
/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.0.jar,\
/spark/spark-examples_2.10-1.1.1.jar,\
/hbase/jar_files-9/* pyspark-shell'
```

Comment: I pretty much sure this is wrong hbase client version or class path issue, could you verify what hbase client version you are actually using? Try to add following props and check
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class'
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class'

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem today. Here is my solution. The error is caused by that the `spark-examples-*.jar` used a low-version `hbase-client` package (0.98), which is not compatible with `hbase-client 2.*`. So what we need to do is to make a little change and re-package it.

1. Download spark from http://spark.apache.org/
2. edit HBaseConverters.scale
3. mvn clean install -e -X -pl :spark-examples_2.11_hardfixed

Maybe I can attach my fixed jar here later.